# Elasticsearch: Searching full text search on Parent Documents only

Tags: elasticsearch, parent-child, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-plugin

I am using join_fields to store documents with parent and child relationships. 
Both parents and child have text data which needs to be searched for different use cases. The has_parent and has_children query are working fine for the standard use cases.

However, one of the use cases for me is to search parent documents based on text fields in parent documents and return the parent ID of the parent document.

Problem is that performing the following query gives higher score to the parents which have atleast one children irrespective of the fact the query text matches text of the other parent document (without children) very nearly.

```
client.search({
   index: '**',
   body: {
   query: {
     match: {
      text: "**"       
     }
   }
  },
}).then((res)=>{
   console.log(res.hits.hits[0]);
})
```

Does simple match query not work for join relationships?

Goal: I want to search the most relevant parent document based on parent document text field independent of its children and retrieve its parent_id.